# move rows to the first row (as new columns) pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm kind of new to `pandas` and I'm trying to perform some table manipulation. I'm not exactly sure how the action I'm looking for is called.

I have a pandas dataframe (the actual one is larger, but these are the cols I need to convert:

```
   pr10      pr50      pr90
25.6214   30.2753    36.634
1.94509   3.84798   6.55111
      0         0   0.00835
      0         0  0.007279
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
pr10_0  pr50_0  pr90_0  pr10_1  pr50_1  pr90_1  pr10_2  pr50_2  pr90_2  pr10_3  pr50_3  pr90_3  pr10_4  pr50_4  pr90_4
25.6214 30.2753 36.634  1.94509 3.84798 6.55111 0   0   0.00835 0   0   0.007279    0.003505    0.007009    0.014764
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please paste the code that you have tried and the current result of the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could recreate the dataframe:

Create new columns from current dataframe

```
cols = [name+'_{}'.format(num // len(df.columns)) for num,name in enumerate(df.columns.tolist()*len(df))]
```

Create a new dataframe by flattening all the values from the original dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(1,-1),columns=cols)
```

---

```
   pr10_0   pr50_0  pr90_0   pr10_1   pr50_1   pr90_1  pr10_2  pr50_2  \
0  25.6214  30.2753  36.634  1.94509  3.84798  6.55111     0.0     0.0   
    pr90_2  pr10_3  pr50_3    pr90_3  
0  0.00835     0.0     0.0  0.007279
```

Comment: What a great and elegant answer. Thanks. One tiny comment- you forgot to close the parentheses after the `format` , it should be- `df.columns))`

Answer (score 1):

Using `stack` and join the multiple index

```
df1=df.stack().to_frame(0).T

df1.columns=df1.columns.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format) 
df1
Out[445]: 
    pr10_0   pr50_0  pr90_0   pr10_1   pr50_1   pr90_1  pr10_2  pr50_2  \
0  25.6214  30.2753  36.634  1.94509  3.84798  6.55111     0.0     0.0   
    pr90_2  pr10_3  pr50_3    pr90_3  
0  0.00835     0.0     0.0  0.007279
```

Comment: This is also a great answer, but unfortunately I can't mark 2 answers. Also, a tiny comment, in your answer you assume that my index in consecutive starting from 0, but it is not since the df is a slice of a bigger df, so I'll have to re-index the slice every time, which is not a problem